# apply jquery editInPlace plugin to a FancyBox iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, iframe, fancybox

I currently am using FancyBox to launch an iframe with text. I would like to use jquery's editInPlace plugin to allow the user to edit the text in the iframe.  This is all on the same domain, in an intranet.

Here is how I'm calling my iframe:

```
<a class="read_more fancybox.iframe" href="iframe.html" data-id="01/01/2012" title="Mgmt Approvals Required" >Read more</a>
```

The fancybox iFrame loads fine and the text is read in. Here is how I am trying to call the editInPlace plugin:

```
        $(".fancybox.iframe").contents().find('#edittext').html(
        $('#edittext').editInPlace({
            callback: function(unused, enteredText) { return enteredText; },
            // url: './server.php',
            show_buttons: true
        })
    );
```

But no luck.  Any idea how I should be calling the editInPlace code?

Here is iframe.html - pretty basic:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mgmt Approval</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />       
</head>
<body>


<h1>Management Approval Required</h1>
    <div id = "edittext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque justo ac eros consectetur bibendum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla aliquam turpis et tellus elementum luctus. Duis sit amet rhoncus velit. Duis nisl ligula, mattis interdum blandit laoreet, mattis id ante. Cras pulvinar lacus vitae nisi egestas non euismod neque bibendum. Vestibulum faucibus libero id ante molestie ultricies. Vestibulum quis nibh felis. Vestibulum libero nisl, vehicula vel ullamcorper sit amet, tristique sit amet augue. Etiam urna neque, porttitor sed sodales lacinia, posuere a nisl. Vestibulum blandit neque in sapien volutpat ac condimentum sapien auctor. Ut imperdiet venenatis ultricies. Phasellus accumsan, sem eu placerat commodo, felis purus commodo ipsum, sit amet vulputate orci est viverra est.
    </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you do that at iframe.html?

Comment: I tried that also and it did not work.

Comment: Could you post the content of iframe.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this :

```
$(".fancybox.iframe").contents().find .....
```

...should be :

```
$(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find .....
```

`.fancybox.iframe` is the *class* of the selector where you fired fancybox from, not the fancybox `iframe` *class*

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.x. ...If using v1.3.4, then the selector is `#fancybox-iframe`

On the other hand, if you already found the selector `#edittext` then you wouldn't need the `.html()` method so:

```
$(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find('#edittext').editInPlace({
   callback: function(unused, enteredText) { return enteredText; },
   // url: './server.php',
   show_buttons: true
 }); // editInPlace
```

**UPDATE** (Nov 13, 2012) : in your post you said `The fancybox iFrame loads fine and the text is read in` so I assumed that just one part of your code was referring to the wrong selector but I guess I should be more specific and say that you have to call the *editInPlace* plugin inside the `afterShow` fancybox callback ... so the full code should look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".read_more").fancybox({
   width: "70%", // or whatever
   height: 400,
   fitToView: false,
   autoSize : false,
   afterShow : function(){
    $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find('#edittext').editInPlace({
       callback: function(unused, enteredText) { return enteredText; },
       // url: "./server.php",
       show_buttons: true
    }); // editInPlace
   } // afterShow
 }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

that should do the trick for fancybox v2.1.3

**[SEE DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/editInPlace_fancybox_13nov12.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but neither option worked. I'm using FancyBox 2.1.3. Everything is loading (I'm checking that thru Firebug), but no errors

Comment: That works - almost!  The iframe initially loads correctly with all my text.  As soon as I click to edit, the text completely disappears, though I still have the text area and two buttons.  Interesting in that your demo works at your link, but when I port it to my system, it does the same thing as my code (iframe loads, then all text disappears).  I copied over all the scripts from your demo to make sure I was using the same code.

Comment: unfortunately this is on an intranet at my company.  I can try and upload code to a freebie site tomorrow.

Comment: *Solved*.  I added field_type: textarea and my code is there to edit. Thanks for all the help